# Share extension need to restrict in some cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

In my app I'm using share extension for share images and videos. All working fine. I need to restrict my app extension when image and video both are selected.

Comment: I don't know if its possible to handle it from Info.plist itself, but if you want to handle it from code use isContentValid()  method to restrict sharing.